# Are there ANY negative effects from the Super-Soldier Serum?

Tags: marvel, captain-america

Is there a downside to the serum? It seems pretty much perfect.

Comment: have you seen the movie?

Comment: @Himarm Uh....nope. Is that important? :D

Comment: yes>.> lol essentially they cant make it anymore and dont have any left.

Comment: @Himarm Hah. I just found that out. I've updated my question to be something totally different.

Comment: No notable negative side effects with the correct formula and method of application, but removal of the serum ages the subject (see recent comic events). Also, when everything is not perfect, really bad things happen - like Abomination (see The Incredible Hulk).

Comment: @phantom42 In the MCU at least, it was a serum reverse-engineered from Banner/Hulk's blood *combined* with an imperfect super-soldier serum that made Abomination.

Comment: @phantom42: Nice! Still no cure for Rob Liefeld

Comment: Please don't fight to create unnecessary tags, [tag:comment-made-by-jack-b-nimble]

Comment: The Red Skull is another example of what can happen with a "bad batch" of Super-soldier Serum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When properly implemented, the only appreciable side effect seems to be that a) Captain America can't get drunk or high and b) his longevity means he will likely see almost everyone he loves wither away and die. One could probably argue that his great endurance and strength probably means that Steve spends most of his day feeling like he's not getting enough exercise and that he needs to go out and run a few miles or lift a few tons in much the same way that many athletes feel antsy if they don't get around to their workouts, but it seems like they give him sufficient exercise that that seldom kicks in.

[image: Captain America's exercise plan]

Of course, the majority of cases where the [Super-Soldier serum](http://marvel.wikia.com/Super-Soldier_Serum) has been administered have led to body deformation, insanity, and such. Whether this is due to an imperfect process or the serum only working due to some quirk in Steve's personal build has varied over the years. Notable failures include Isaiah Bradley (brain damaged and rendered sterile), the other members of his team (deformities and rage problems), the Anti-Cap (insanity), Protocide (initially death, later insanity), Steven Burnside (insanity), and The Sentry (batshit insanity).

**The Black Super Soldiers including Isaiah Bradley**
[image: Super-Soldier failures]

Comment: Cap has dealt with [his own body deformation](http://www.newstatesman.com/sites/default/files/styles/fullnode_image/public/articles_2012/cap.png)

Comment: Can you provide some context/explanation for that picture of a bunch of bulky raisin-looking dudes? I'm not sure how it relates to the answer or question.

Comment: @TylerH: I've labeled the picture. They're the team that worked with Isaiah Bradley. They're the best case for induced deformities I could find.

Comment: “he will likely see almost everyone he loves wither away and die” — that would sound great in the classic super-fast medicine advert side-effects disclaimer voice.

Comment: ^_^ Honestly, Protocide amused me more. "Side effects may include: death, insanity, death *then* insanity."